# Screenshot of the specific window (HWND, HW accelerated)

Tags: windows, screenshot, screen-capture, dwm, screen-recording

I need to capture a snapshots/screenshots of the specific window (HWND) that is using HW acceleration and record them to a video stream.

While using `BitBlt` or `PrintWindow` I'm able to capture image data only if this window is not HW accelerated, else I'm getting a black texture.

Tried using **User32.dll**'s undocumented `DwmGetDxSharedSurface` to get the DirectX surface handle. But it fails with an error:

> ERROR_GRAPHICS_PRESENT_REDIRECTION_DISABLED - desktop windowing
>   management subsystem is off
>
> (Edit: Fails for certain applications, i.e. "calculator.exe")

Tried using **Dwmapi.dll**'s undocumented functions `DwmpDxUpdateWindowSharedSurface` and `DwmpDxGetWindowSharedSurface`. I've managed to retrieve what looks like a valid DirectX surface handle. (*it's d3dFormat, width and height information was valid*) Dx's `OpenSharedResource` was not complaining and managed to create a valid `ID3D11Texture2D`. Problem is.. all bytes are zeros (getting a black texture). I might be doing something wrong here or.. undocumented DWM functionas does not work anymore on Windows 10...

> Edit: I'm able to get image data for some applications like Windows
>   explorer, Paint, etc, but for some like i.e. Slack i get all
>   zeros/black image.

Edit: When capturing i.e. VLC, I get this: [image]

**Question**:
Is there any other way to capture image data of the HW accelerated window?

**Note**: I don't want to capture the entire desktop.

Comment: Which technology is the application using? Does it only fail on UWP apps? Does the DWM thumbnail API work or is it also blank?

Comment: @Anders I was testing with windows calculator.exe. DWM thumbnail is able to capture and show the duplicated "thumbnail" image in my window. But DwmGetDxSharedSurface (User32.dll) fails with the specified error.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am having the same issue

Comment: @user1428926 I did not, if you will, please let me know.

Comment: @Gediminas do you still have the code for DwmGetDxSharedSurface() or DwmpDxGetWindowSharedSurface()

Comment: @trickymind, take a look: https://pastebin.com/i9ibFX99 It's just some old experimental trash code. Hope you'll find something useful.

Comment: @Gediminas Thank you so much for helping, i have been surfing internet for a week to get a sample code of this Dwm Function

Comment: @trickymind, np, additionally, try and take a look: https://spazzarama.com/2009/02/12/screen-capture-with-vista-dwm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PrintWindow with nFlags=2
Or use Magnification API (exclude windows)
Or try to hack dwm.exe.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of the "PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT" flag (nFlags=2). There is no information about it in the "PrintWindow" documentation..